# 1 button 2 functions

Tags: javascript, php

I've got a conflict issue with a form. The idea is that I need to store the datas in the form field in a table with a local storage in Javascript, and I need to send an email simultaneously with the same button with PHP. When I try it, either the button implement the table, either it send the mail. It depends of the position of the action inside the arrows. Here is my code :

```js
<script>
    var Contacts = {
      index: window.localStorage.getItem("Contacts:index"),
      $table: document.getElementById("contacts-table"),
      $form: document.getElementById("contacts-form"),
      $button_save: document.getElementById("contacts-op-save"),
      $button_discard: document.getElementById("contacts-op-discard"),

      init: function() {
        // initialize storage index
        if (!Contacts.index) {
          window.localStorage.setItem("Contacts:index", Contacts.index = 1);
        }

        // initialize form
        Contacts.$form.reset();
        Contacts.$button_discard.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
          Contacts.$form.reset();
          Contacts.$form.id_entry.value = 0;
        }, true);
        Contacts.$form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
          var entry = {
            id: parseInt(this.id_entry.value),
            first_name: this.first_name.value,
            last_name: this.last_name.value,
            company: this.company.value,
            address: this.address.value,
            city: this.city.value,
            zip: this.zip.value,
            state: this.state.value,
            country: this.country.value,
            phone: this.phone.value,
            email: this.email.value,
            nature_of_contact: this.nature_of_contact.value,
          };
          if (entry.id == 0) { // add
            Contacts.storeAdd(entry);
            Contacts.tableAdd(entry);
          }
          else { // edit
            Contacts.storeEdit(entry);
            Contacts.tableEdit(entry);
          }

          this.reset();
          this.id_entry.value = 0;
          event.preventDefault();
        }, true);

        // initialize table
        if (window.localStorage.length - 1) {
          var contacts_list = [], i, key;
          for (i = 0; i < window.localStorage.length; i++) {
            key = window.localStorage.key(i);
            if (/Contacts:\d+/.test(key)) {
              contacts_list.push(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key)));
            }
          }

          if (contacts_list.length) {
            contacts_list
              .sort(function(a, b) {
                return a.id < b.id ? -1 : (a.id > b.id ? 1 : 0);
              })
              .forEach(Contacts.tableAdd);
          }
        }
        Contacts.$table.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
          var op = event.target.getAttribute("data-op");
          if (/edit|remove/.test(op)) {
            var entry = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("Contacts:"+ event.target.getAttribute("data-id")));
            if (op == "edit") {
              Contacts.$form.first_name.value = entry.first_name;
              Contacts.$form.last_name.value = entry.last_name;
              Contacts.$form.company.value = entry.company;
              Contacts.$form.address.value = entry.address;
              Contacts.$form.city.value = entry.city;
              Contacts.$form.zip.value = entry.zip;
              Contacts.$form.state.value = entry.state;
              Contacts.$form.country.value = entry.country;
              Contacts.$form.phone.value = entry.phone;
              Contacts.$form.email.value = entry.email;
              Contacts.$form.nature_of_contact.value = entry.nature_of_contact;
              Contacts.$form.id_entry.value = entry.id;
            }
            else if (op == "remove") {
              if (confirm('Are you sure you want to remove "'+ entry.first_name +' '+ entry.last_name +'" from your contacts?')) {
                Contacts.storeRemove(entry);
                Contacts.tableRemove(entry);
              }
            }
            event.preventDefault();
          }
        }, true);
      },

      storeAdd: function(entry) {
        entry.id = Contacts.index;
        window.localStorage.setItem("Contacts:index", ++Contacts.index);
        window.localStorage.setItem("Contacts:"+ entry.id, JSON.stringify(entry));
      },
      storeEdit: function(entry) {
        window.localStorage.setItem("Contacts:"+ entry.id, JSON.stringify(entry));
      },
      storeRemove: function(entry) {
        window.localStorage.removeItem("Contacts:"+ entry.id);
      },

      tableAdd: function(entry) {
        var $tr = document.createElement("tr"), $td, key;
        for (key in entry) {
          if (entry.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            $td = document.createElement("td");
            $td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry[key]));
            $tr.appendChild($td);
          }
        }
        $td = document.createElement("td");
        $td.innerHTML = '<a data-op="edit" data-id="'+ entry.id +'">Edit</a> | <a data-op="remove" data-id="'+ entry.id +'">Remove</a>';
        $tr.appendChild($td);
        $tr.setAttribute("id", "entry-"+ entry.id);
        Contacts.$table.appendChild($tr);
      },
      tableEdit: function(entry) {
        var $tr = document.getElementById("entry-"+ entry.id), $td, key;
        $tr.innerHTML = "";
        for (key in entry) {
          if (entry.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            $td = document.createElement("td");
            $td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry[key]));
            $tr.appendChild($td);
          }
        }
        $td = document.createElement("td");
        $td.innerHTML = '<a data-op="edit" data-id="'+ entry.id +'">Edit</a> | <a data-op="remove" data-id="'+ entry.id +'">Remove</a>';
        $tr.appendChild($td);
      },
      tableRemove: function(entry) {
        Contacts.$table.removeChild(document.getElementById("entry-"+ entry.id));
      }
    };
    Contacts.init();
  </script>
```

```html
<form action="mailer.php" method="post" class="onerow">
           
      <label class="col6">First name:
      <input type="text" name="first_name" />
      </label>
   
      <label class="col6">Last name:
      <input type="text" name="last_name" />
      </label>

      <label class="col6">Company:
     <input type="text" name="company" />
     </label>
    
      <label class="col6">Address:
      <input type="text" name="address" />
      </label>

      <label class="col6">City:
      <input type="text" name="city" />
      </label>

      <label class="col6">Postal/zip code:
      <input type="text" name="zip" />
      </label>

      <label class="col6">State/province:
      <input type="text" name="state" />
      </label>

      <label class="col6">Country:
      <input type="text" name="country" />
      </label>

      <label class="col6">Phone number:
     <input type="text" name="phone" />
      </label>

      <label class="col6">Email:
      <input type="text" name="email" />
      </label>

      <label class="col12">Why are you looking for our solutions ?
      
        <SELECT name="nature_of_contact" size="1">
          <OPTION>I'm a distributor and I want to sell your products in my country.
          <OPTION>I'm a beautician I want to buy a product.
          <OPTION>I'm a doctor.
          <OPTION>I'm a distributor.
        </SELECT>
      </label>
    
    <div class="col12">
      <input type="button" id="contacts-op-discard" value="Discard" />
       <input type="submit" id="contacts-op-save" value="Save" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id_entry" value="0" />
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
  <div></div>
  <div id="tablecontrol" class="col12">
  <h1>Contacts</h1>
  <table id="contacts-table">
    <tr id="contacts-head">
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Postal/Zip</th>
      <th>State/province</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Phone number</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Kind of prospect</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  </div>
```

See [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/theblaisyblaise/gb028g90/)

Comment: Please mark Daenu's answer as 'Accepted answer'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

1. Add an `event.preventDefault()` to your handler
2. Then store things in `localStorage`
3. If things are stored submit the form with `Contacts.$form.submit();`

**EDIT**

Change the event handler from `submit` to `click` and remove it from the form to add it to the `Contacts.$button_save` button and add a `preventDefault()` just after.

As you changed the event handler from the form to the button you need to change the form values from `this` to `Contacts.$form` because `this` was in the scope of the form which is not the case anymore.

```
Contacts.$button_save.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var entry = {
        id: parseInt(Contacts.$form.id_entry.value),
        first_name: Contacts.$form.first_name.value,
        last_name: Contacts.$form.last_name.value,
   // and so on
```

Remove the `input type="submit"` and create a normal button instead:

```
<button id="contacts-op-save">Save</button>
```

Then you could submit the form after storing in `storeAdd` / `storeEdit` functions as said with `Contacts.$form.submit();`.

```
      storeAdd: function(entry) {
        entry.id = Contacts.index;
        window.localStorage.setItem("Contacts:index", ++Contacts.index);
        window.localStorage.setItem("Contacts:"+ entry.id, JSON.stringify(entry));
        Contacts.$form.submit();
      },
      storeEdit: function(entry) {
        window.localStorage.setItem("Contacts:"+ entry.id, JSON.stringify(entry));
        Contacts.$form.submit();
      },
      storeRemove: function(entry) {
        window.localStorage.removeItem("Contacts:"+ entry.id);
        // eventually here too?
        Contacts.$form.submit();

      },
```

Also you call the form element by its id , but the form has no id assigned.

```
$form: document.getElementById("contacts-form")
```

So give your form that ID:

```
<form id="contacts-form" action="mailer.php" method="post" class="onerow">
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm trying but I'm afraid I'm not adding the code at the right place. Could you show me where exactly doing this please ?

Comment: I do the modifications, thanks for the explanation. I recieved the mail but no data stored :/

Comment: ok so I've got old values in the table, but when I click on the button, I've got neither new storage nor email.

Comment: Hmm I copied your whole thing and tested it: I've got saved form values in `localStorage` and I received `$_POST` vars too, so.... I don't know where the error could be...

Comment: Maybe you should create a jsfiddle or similar & post the link here... I'll check it

Comment: Ok You didn't read my answer right... The `$buttton_save` event isn't changed at all. You just changed the edit event...

Comment: I'm definitely blind. Many thanks for you @Daenu for your help, All works and this rocks !!!

Comment: @Honoréotisreddingbrown Could you eventually accept my answer as the one?

Comment: oh sorry  I forgot that. Thank you again. Done.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be:

1. Change the submit button from type 'submit' to 'button' and add the event `onClick()`to it.
2. Create a function -let's say `readFromdata()`- that reads the values from your form. Store the data into a container.
3. Create a function -let's say `sendFromdata()`- that sends the data to your php script. Hint: Ajax would be your friend. Configure your Ajax so, that the data will be send asyncrosly.
4. Create a function -let's say `printFOverview()`- that extends your html table, for the displaying the result.
5. Call `sendFromdata()` and `printFOverview()` within the function `readFromdata()` and pass the data container to these methods.
6. Add the call `readFromdata()` to the attribute `onClick()`.